# How to find repeated different patterns inside a string

Tags: python, regex

```
input_string = '7:30 p.m. 7:20 p.m.every Mon., any Wed.Thu,fri'
```

I want to get like this:

```
print match.group('day')= mon, wed, thu, fri
print match.group('starttime')= 7:30 p.m, 7:20 p.m
```

I tried this:

```
match = re.search(r'(?P<starttime>([\d]*:[\d]*)(?:[ .apm]*m)?)
         .*?(?P<day>(?i)(?:mon(?:day)?|tue(?:sday)?|wed(?:nesday)?|
         thu(?:rsday)?|fri(?:day)?|sat(?:urday)?|sun(?:day)?))'
             , input_string)
```

But I didn't get correctly.

Comment: Why the `m` after `[ .apm]*`?

Comment: And presumably your pattern is all on *one* line without whitespace?

Comment: am or pm.this is a test string.

Comment: Without spaces your pattern works for me. What output do you get instead? What is the *exact* code you are running (not linewrapped)?

Comment: As for `[ .apm]*m`; that makes the pattern match `..ampam` too. It looks a little redundant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i get only "mon" for match.group('day')

Comment: Right, yes, your pattern matches only the first match, not all matches.

Comment: Your pattern cannot match the trailing days here, because that's not part of the match. Your `day` group cannot repeat, regular expressions cannot do that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then can i get repeated group matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use separate patterns for the time and day sections, then use `.findall()` to find multiple matches:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?P<starttime>[\d]*:[\d]*(?:[ .apm]*m)?)', input_string)
['7:30 p.m', '7:20 p.m']
>>> re.findall(r'(?P<day>(?i)(?:mon(?:day)?|tue(?:sday)?|wed(?:nesday)?|thu(?:rsday)?|fri(?:day)?|sat(?:urday)?|sun(?:day)?))', input_string)
['Mon', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'fri']
```

The named groups then really are redundant, the following would do:

```
re.findall(r'[\d]*:[\d]*(?:[ .apm]*m)?', input_string)
re.findall(r'(?i)mon(?:day)?|tue(?:sday)?|wed(?:nesday)?|thu(?:rsday)?|fri(?:day)?|sat(?:urday)?|sun(?:day)?', input_string)
```

Comment: @Martin thanks.but sad to know that there is no option in regex to match repeated pattern groups :( ;)

Comment: A pattern group is like a single variable; it cannot hold a list. So either you add a fixed list of capturing groups, or you capture all text containing multiple matches in one group then split after matching with separate code, or you do what I did in the answer here, which is the simplest and easiest method.